# Matrix norm if we don't specify the vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Is it possible to compute the norm
$$
||A||=\sup_{X\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\lVert AX\rVert}{\lVert X\rVert}
$$
where $A$ is the matrice defined by $AX=(x_1-x_n,x_2-x_1,\ldots,x_n-x_{n-1})$?

I can compute it given the norm is defined as the Frobenius norm: $\lVert X\rVert=^t X X$ and we obtain the square root of the maximum of the eigenvalues of $^t A A$. But if we don't specify the norm $\lVert\cdot \rVert$ is it possible to determine $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ ?

Comment: $\| A \|$ will vary depending on what norm you use for the vector norm.  It's unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: No. See the example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases